Getting Error: spawn git ENOENT on build via sfp
I am trying to setup sfp by following the instructions: flxbl Docs
I am trying to run below command as mentioned here:
sfp build -v MySandboxOrg

Getting below error output:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sfp  -- ❤️ by flxbl.io ❤️ -Version:38.4.1 -Release:April 24
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    command: build
Build Packages Only Changed: false
Config File Path: config/project-scratch-def.json
Artifact Directory: artifacts
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error: Error: spawn git ENOENT
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:285:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:483:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)

Is anyone aware of this?

spawn is a POSIX command, which tries to run an executable, in this case, git. The command wasn't able to find the command, so it returned ENOENT, meaning the executable couldn't be found. This may be the same problem that you had in this question, where you just need to configure your PATH variable, or you might have installed Git for use only in Git Bash/WSL/etc (i.e. a proper Linux system), in which case, try running your command from Bash or Command Prompt (cmd.exe).

Installing https://www.git-scm.com/download/win have resolved the issue.
